# Passar dado criptografado por URL em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, criptografia

Estou precisando passar um link, mas não queria deixar ele muito exposto, gostaria de saber como Criptografar pelo menos o id do objeto. Criei uma classe para Criptografia, só que a mesma gera "/" e isso coloca como rota no MVC.

Answer (score 2):

Continue usando a sua criptografia nos parâmetros, mas para evitar problemas com caracteres não permitidos na Url, antes de enviar a string, utilize o método [HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx).

Ao ler novamente a string, utilize o método [HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt(v=vs.110).aspx).

Quando estiver fora de uma aplicação ASP.NET, se estiver usando o Framework 4.5 em diante, o recomendável é usar a classe [WebUtility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility(v=vs.100).aspx) para acessar os métodos `UrlEncode` e `UrlDecode`.

Comment: esse  HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode() posso utilizar no controller? estou tentando mas ele está dando erro no Current...

Comment: Tente `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`, ou `WebUtility.UrlDecode` se estiver no Framwork 4.5.

Comment: o link ficou dessa forma: http://localhost:63896/Chamado/ReaberturaChamado/LiUYCXqMgEQ/F%2buF/DdAsEXoxA8kJloS7NRQ3qfw93UZjmQAQ2KW3iWy%2bZ3Zn2HO, porem ainda não abriu, dá erro no IIS, deve ser pq não estou colocando como QueryString isso?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Regex regex1 = new Regex("/");
string result = rgx.Replace('SEU TEXTO CRIPTOGRAFADO', 'QUALQUER SIMBOLO QUE NÃO É USADO E NÃO CAUSA PROBLEMAS';
```

depois adicione o resultado ao URL e na hora de converter use:

```
Regex regex1 = new Regex('SIMBOLO USADO');
string result = rgx.Replace('SEU TEXTO CRIPTOGRAFADO E CODIFICADO', "/";
```

Outra forma seria usando POST, no qual faria seu site ficar mais seguro.
Essa criptografia não me parece muito segura, seria bom pesquisar uma classe de criptografia já existente se você deseja mais segurança.